# Can a component access the viewmodel of another not-related component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using Typescript, React and Material-UI. Plain React, no Redux, Flux, etc.

When I click a button in **ButtonComponent**, I need to scroll to **TabsComponent** and select a specific tab. These components don't have a parent-child relation.

```
<ResultsComponent>
  ...
  <ButtonComponent/>
  ...
</ResultsComponent>
<ReportComponent>
  <TabsComponent/>
  ...
<ReportComponent>
```

In **TabsComponent** I have a viewModel to manage some logic and to store the *selectedTabId*

In **ButtonComponent** I have an *onClick* event which gets the position of **TabsComponent** and uses *window.scrollTo(...)* to perform the scrolling. It also gets the *tabId* to which I need to switch, but I'm not sure if there is a way to access the viewModel in **TabsComponent** and set the property *selectedTabId*.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using Mobx observables.

I have a parent component whose childs are **ResultsComponent** and **ReportComponent**.
In this parent I've created an @observable variable *selectedTabId* to hold the TabId of the tab I want to show as selected, and an @observable function to change that *selectedTabId*.

So I pass the function (or callback) to the **ResultsComponent** and execute it during the onClick event. This sets the value of *selectedTabId*.
I also pass the variable *selectedTabId* to the **ReportComponent** and then to the **TabsComponent** and use it to set the selected tab. Since it is and @observable, every time the callback is executed in **ButtonComponent** the tabs are changed in **TabsComponent**